# How to create multiple files(100 files) and they can contain 30 random characters in each of them using script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to create 100 files using script Linux which contain 30 random characters password and that password contain only strings, small letters and big letters.
And the name of each file will be " Business.txt "

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in {1..100}; do
{ < /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c${1:-30};echo; } > /mnt/mymnt/passwords/$n done
```

Comment: Put a semicolon before `done`, and it will work, if the directory `/mnt/mymnt/passwords`exists and you are allowed to write in it.

Comment: It gives me a " tr: write error: Broken pipe " That's actually my question.

Comment: Try this `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | fold -w 29 | head -n 1 > Business.txt`

Comment: You might also need to create folders to contain those files as all have the same name and will simply over write each other...

Comment: for n in {1..100}; do { < /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c${1:-30};echo; } > `passwords/$n; done` works for me and creates 100 files (with password strings) in the subdirectory `passwords` :-)

Comment: The code is good, but the problem is that I am getting this error still.

Comment: Are you allowed to write, where you want to write (ownership and permissions)?

Comment: Yes, I have gave the file the permissions, and still not working

Comment: Which file did you give permissions?

Comment: The .sh file which is the script

Comment: Yes, but the problem might be the permissions and ownership of the target directory.

Comment: You should [edit] this question and share the _exact_ message you get when you run this one-liner.

Comment: The exact message is tr: write error: Broken pipe. I have searched for this error on other threads but didn't find the solution yet.

Comment: @Onyic Q&A should be standalone without any info in the comments. [Edit] your question and put all details in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a good practice to open a file one hundred times when it’s actually needed just once, so how about this:

```
#!/bin/bash
random=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c3000)
for i in {1..100}; do
  echo ${random:(i-1)*30:30} >/mnt/mymnt/passwords/Business$i.txt
done
```

This first saves 3000 random characters matching `A-Za-z0-9` in the variable `$random` and then loops over the numbers 1–100 cutting parts of 30 characters out  and saving them.

Answer (score 1):

When writing this answer, I thought you can get what you want the following way, but it is not yet clear how you want to store the passwords.

1. Change directory to where you want to write the file `Business.txt`.
2. Test that you can create the file manually,

   ```
   echo 'testing' > Business.txt
   cat Business.txt
   ```
3. Modify ownership and permissions if necessary. The method depends on the file system.
4. Create the passwords,

   ```
   for n in {1..100}; do { < /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c${1:-30};echo; } ;done > Business.txt
   ```
5. Check the passwords in `Business.txt`

   ```
   $ cat Business.txt 
   7rmJFCq2CZ9azpuxywFLwbjhmL2dD4
   dtLSVAEtDmyLUglkYFgUeGc9PDKBPb
   E3bnJ8WF4qoyS1Tokp6reAcpIkuLUt
   Y5whhtbJn1KfAccp85547gNDji2xLY
   ...
   ```

   There should be 100 lines

   ```
   $ wc -l Business.txt 
   100 Business.txt
   ```

Edit:

You want 100 files with different names (and one password in each file). So the steps can be modified according to this following list.

2.1. Remove the test file.

```
    rm Business.txt
```

4. Modified command line: write to the target files inside the loop.

   ```
   for n in {1..100}; do { < /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c${1:-30};echo; } > Business"$n".txt; done
   ```
5. Check that the files were written

   ```
   $ ls
   Business100.txt  Business28.txt  Business46.txt  Business64.txt  Business82.txt
   Business10.txt   Business29.txt  Business47.txt  Business65.txt  Business83.txt
   Business11.txt   Business2.txt   Business48.txt  Business66.txt  Business84.txt
   Business12.txt   Business30.txt  Business49.txt  Business67.txt  Business85.txt
   Business13.txt   Business31.txt  Business4.txt   Business68.txt  Business86.txt
   Business14.txt   Business32.txt  Business50.txt  Business69.txt  Business87.txt
   Business15.txt   Business33.txt  Business51.txt  Business6.txt   Business88.txt
   Business16.txt   Business34.txt  Business52.txt  Business70.txt  Business89.txt
   Business17.txt   Business35.txt  Business53.txt  Business71.txt  Business8.txt
   Business18.txt   Business36.txt  Business54.txt  Business72.txt  Business90.txt
   Business19.txt   Business37.txt  Business55.txt  Business73.txt  Business91.txt
   Business1.txt    Business38.txt  Business56.txt  Business74.txt  Business92.txt
   Business20.txt   Business39.txt  Business57.txt  Business75.txt  Business93.txt
   Business21.txt   Business3.txt   Business58.txt  Business76.txt  Business94.txt
   Business22.txt   Business40.txt  Business59.txt  Business77.txt  Business95.txt
   Business23.txt   Business41.txt  Business5.txt   Business78.txt  Business96.txt
   Business24.txt   Business42.txt  Business60.txt  Business79.txt  Business97.txt
   Business25.txt   Business43.txt  Business61.txt  Business7.txt   Business98.txt
   Business26.txt   Business44.txt  Business62.txt  Business80.txt  Business99.txt
   Business27.txt   Business45.txt  Business63.txt  Business81.txt  Business9.txt
   ```

   There should be 100 files (with one password in each file)

   ```
   $ ls -1 Business*|wc -l
   100
   ```
6. Check the passwords in `Business1.txt`, `Business2.txt` ...

   ```
   $ cat Business*
   43xx3zUEJ5wCPLzhagmQJcWHP2cvW1
   GCRZ8uJdxQEKXRBc2hoZREpiWseFll
   CKwYTghXjJOcBuufODKWnFohG1TKel
   ZMXPyNTxIENfoWlF7cfkPxCBkQpLt1
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could readily find to get something from /dev/urandom for what you want is to use the dd command.  Since /dev/urandom outputs raw bits, using your tr command will get printable characters, but if you want 30 printable characters, you need to get more than 30 bytes from dd.  So, I went with 300.  You can the use the cut command to get the first 30 printable characters.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in {1..100}; do
  p=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=300 2>/dev/null | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | cut -c 1-30)
  echo "${p}" >${n}
done

exit 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know it's a silly question but I am new to Linux, should I put the file name instead of the n? I mean like this : " >echo "${p}" >${Business.txt}

Comment: no `${Business.txt}` isn't a defined variable and I think you will get an error along the lines of **bad substitution**

Comment: Well, I want to print this into the directory /mnt/mymnt/passwords in the file Business.txt which is inside the directory passwords.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want your output to be.  Do you want one file with the passwords in them, or do you want a password in each file, or do you want a file called Business.txt inside of a directory, and each directory only contains that single file?  Please edit your question to show what kind of output you want.

Comment: Okay, lets make it clear. I need to create 100 files into the directory /mnt/mymnt/passwords .. which every file will have the name of Business.txt .. and every file contains maximum 30 random characters (Big, small letters and strings)

Comment: @Onyic, you can only have one file with a particular name in a particular directory. You can have 1. 100 passwords in one files; 2. 100 files with different names (and one password in each file) in one directory; 3. 100 directories with different names and one file with a standard name (and one password in each file) in each directory.